# How do I show a static html file uploaded by user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

User can upload static html file on my site.

I stored the file with paperclip.

But How could I show the html in an new window with clicking the link, without downloading it.

That's say. every user can upload its resume file in **HTML format**

Then we can see the resume by click = `User.find_by_id(ID).resume.url`

But I don't want to download the html file.

I want to open an new window or hsow it in the current window or iframe

How could I do it ?

Thanks~

Comment: I strongly recommend against doing this because of security issues. You will be allowing anybody to upload html... and then running it on your server without checking that it's ok? Not a good idea. Don't forget that html can include scripts and all kinds of nasties.

Comment: Actually is for our internal use. thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you store them:

1. If you store HTML in the database, you can do something like the following:

   - Add a route:

     ```
     get '/resume/:id' => 'resume#show'
     ```
   - Create a controller:

     ```
     class ResumeController < ApplicationController
       def show
         render html: resume_html(params[:id]).html_safe
       end

       private

       def resume_html(id)
         # here you should return your resume HTML by either
         # just returning a string
         "<h1>Resume</h1>"
         # ... or reading it from a file (this assumes UTF8 encoding)
         Paperclip.io_adapters.for(User.find_by_id(id).resume).read.
           pack('C*').force_encoding('utf-8')
       end
     end
     ```
2. If you store HTML file somewhere in publicly available place like `#{Rails.root}/public`, then it's just a matter of issuing a redirect in the contoller (don't forget to add a route as well):

   ```
   class ResumeController < ApplicationController
     def show
       redirect_to resume_path(params[:id])
     end

     private

     def resume_path(id)
       # do whatever you need to return resume URL/path
     end
   end
   ```

Hope this helps!